# Slow internet on Windows 10 but fast on Ubuntu - Dual Boot

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, windows-10, internet

Not sure how to ask this. My ISP throttles my connection for certain data types at 3pm each day (ie. torrents), this has never been an issue under Ubuntu because it never effects any other kind of browsing or internet work. But since going dual boot with Windows 10, at 3pm on Windows only, my net slows to a crawl, now I know that they are throttling but if I switch back to Ubuntu I can browse and download and upload at normal speeds, so why am I having issues with Windows?